# Пропал Pivot после загрузки проекта в UE4

Tags: разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4, pivot

Я открываю свой проект, и вижу что пропал pivot. Я не могу нормально передвигать объекты.
Я начал искать в интернете, но ничего не нашёл. Помогите пожалуйста
[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я НАШЁЛ РЕШЕНИЕ!. Для тех у кого такая же проблема :

Откройте вкладку Settings. Далее включите Show Transform Widget, и всё.

[image]